# como pegar uma substring de tamanho n que se repete

Tags: java, string, indexof

Tenho a seguinte entrada:

```
aaisndiaunwioun    test|test saiudb8iuyb aiwbu diby tab fiubaw palavragrande|palavragrande asibtiubi
```

Como fazer o algoritmo retornar `test` e `palavragrande` apenas se estiver escrito igual **antes e depois** do index do simbolo `|`

Fiz isso mas obviamente não deu certo

```
while (s1.indexOf("|") != -1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 25; j++) {
                String teste1 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf("|") + 1, s1.indexOf("|") + i);
                String teste2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf("|") - j, s1.indexOf("|"));
                if (teste1.equals(teste2)) {
                    System.out.println(teste1);
                    char[] s1char = s1.toCharArray();
                    s1char[s1.indexOf("|")] = 'a';
                    s1 = String.valueOf(s1char);
                    System.out.println(s1);
                    System.out.println(s1.indexOf("|"));
                }

            }
```

Comment: É padrão ? Tem sempre espaços antes de pois de `test|test` ?

Comment: nao, pode ocorrer de ser qualquer carácter alfanumérico ex: assatest|test    awe

Comment: Caso seja `assatest|test awe` não seria valida ?

Comment: eu preciso q nesse caso ele retorne `test`, na minha ideia seria um comparação char a char pra cima e pra baixo a partir do simbolo `|` ate achar um char diferente

Comment: Não podes simplesmente fazer assim: https://repl.it/repls/DismalUnselfishProfile

Comment: acho que não, quando vc dá de exemplo `aaaa|aabaa` na teoria eles são iguais até o 2 `a` se comparado a partir do simbolo `|` pra frente e pra trás. E o retorno pra mim tem q ser a string q foi verificada no caso acima `aa`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `indexOf("")` para coincidir a sentença inteira:

```
public class Teste {

    private static final String CONST = "aaisndiaunwioun    test|test saiudb8iuyb aiwbu diby tab fiubaw palavragrande|palavragrande asibtiubi";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(CONST.indexOf("test|test") >= 0) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }

        if(CONST.indexOf("palavragrande|palavragrande") >= 0) {
            System.out.println("palavragrande");
        }
    }
}
```

Caso as sentenças `"test|test"` ou `"palavragrande|palavragrande"` não existam o `indexOf("")` retornará `-1`.

---

**EDIT**

Com os comentários abaixo entendi que não era isso o que queria.
Refiz a resposta mas vou deixar o conteúdo original de exemplo.
Segue a resposta correta:

```
public class Teste {

    private static final String CONST = "aaisndiaunwioun    test|test saiudb8iuyb aiwbu diby tab fiubaw palavragrande|palavragrande asibtiubi";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int ultimaPosicaoDoPipe = 0;
        while(CONST.indexOf("|", ultimaPosicaoDoPipe) >= 0) {

            final int posicaoAtualDoPipe = CONST.indexOf("|", ultimaPosicaoDoPipe);
            final String palavraAntesDoPipe = getPalavraAntesDoPipe(ultimaPosicaoDoPipe, posicaoAtualDoPipe);
            final String palavraDepoisDoPipe = getPalavraDepoisDoPipe(posicaoAtualDoPipe);

            if(palavraAntesDoPipe.equals(palavraDepoisDoPipe)) {
                System.out.println(palavraAntesDoPipe);
            }

            ultimaPosicaoDoPipe = posicaoAtualDoPipe + 1;
        }
    }

    private static String getPalavraAntesDoPipe(final int ultimaPosicaoDoPipe, final int posicaoAtualDoPipe) {
        String palavraAntesDoPipe = CONST.substring(ultimaPosicaoDoPipe, posicaoAtualDoPipe);
        palavraAntesDoPipe = palavraAntesDoPipe.substring(palavraAntesDoPipe.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
        return palavraAntesDoPipe;
    }

    private static String getPalavraDepoisDoPipe(final int posicaoAtualDoPipe) {
        String palavraDepoisDoPipe = CONST.substring(posicaoAtualDoPipe + 1);
        palavraDepoisDoPipe = palavraDepoisDoPipe.substring(0, palavraDepoisDoPipe.indexOf(" "));
        return palavraDepoisDoPipe;
    }
}
```

Explicação:

O caractere pipe (`|`) é procurado em loop através da [sobrecarga do método `indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) que recebe um segundo parâmetro que informa a partir de qual index ele deve procurar o pipe.

A partir daí, os métodos `getPalavraAntesDoPipe()` e `getPalavraDepoisDoPipe()` retornam as palavras antes e depois do pipe (como é de se imaginar :p).

Nada muito complexo, apenas uso dos métodos da classe [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: acho q me expressei errado, as palavras test e palavragrande foram somente exemplos, eu imagino palavras aleatórias mas seguindo o padrão de ter o simbolo `|` no meio

Comment: Você saberá quais palavras tem que procurar? Ou vai procurar pelo pipe (`|`) e encontrar as palavras antes e depois?

Comment: eu vou procura-las pelo pipe `|` elas serão randomicas

Comment: @unkbr atualizei a resposta. Poderia ver se agora atende, por favor?! :D